# Extract the single value from a column containing multiple values using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have inserted multiple values from select statement in a single column using implode function. Now I want retrieve those values separately for my further queries. 
I have a student table in which I am storing their different area of interest in a single column using the implode function implode(',', $_POST['aoi']);. The structure of the table is like this:

```
id   |  Name   |           AOI
-------------------------------------------
101  | Paul    | Hardware,Networking
102  | Fred    | Finance,Insurance,Banking
```

Now I want to retrieve this student data separately based on their interest. I tried to extract data using explode function. But it is returning the data in array format.

And I have to extract area of interest separately. Can anybody tell me how to extract the single value from a column containing multiple value. So that I can execute my further queries.

Like $query = "select student.id,student.Name from student where AOI = 'Insurance'";

Thanks.

Comment: Tip number 1, normalise your database. Tip number 2 normalise your database. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: If you use other database like MongoDB, you can add `AOI` as array and store values. But with MYSQL, you need to normalize the database.

Comment: I am a novice database user. I will definitely try to implement normalization concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database structure is fundamentally wrong and it will most likely lead to scalability issues further down the line. You should look into the concept of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In this particular scenario, you should be using a many to many relationship:

Students:

```
id   | name  
---------------
101  | Paul    
102  | Fred
```

StudentInterests

```
id   |  student_id  | interest_id
---------------------------------
1    |  101         | 1
2    |  101         | 2
3    |  102         | 1
```

Interests

```
id   | interest
----------------
1    | Insurance
2    | Networkings
```

Comment: This is the answer, what the hell is with those other answers, geese.